# Structure pytests when a delay is required?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a set of pytest integration tests that are laid out like this:

```
def 001_setup():
    # Set up backend data

def 002_do_first_thing():
    # Use data from 001_set up and modify it

def 003_do_second_thing():
    # Use changed data from 002

def 999_clean_up():
    # Clean up all data from this set of tests
```

The problem I'm running into is that test `002` calls an API end point that is long running. It can take upwards of 20 seconds to complete and report success. Test `003` starts and I can't be guarenteed that `002` completed yet.

How can I better structure this set of tests so that `003` will only begin once `002` has actually completed without filling my tests with a bunch of `time.sleep(20)` commands?

Comment: Your tests should not depend on one another or on the order they run. This is bad practice and now you're seeing why...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the lesser your test functions knows of the outer world, the better your test suite will run without any problems, that's what i believe in. If you really have to run in the way you described, look at pytest-ordering and see if that helps

https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/